# C++ template with char[] argument

Tags: c++, templates

How do I pass a pointer to a C-style array to a template function?

The following doesn't compile with an error like `error: no matching function for call to 'func(char (*)[2])'`

```
// What do I need to change on the next line to make this compile?
template<typename T> bool func(T **var)
{
    return var == 0;
}

int main() {
    char ar[2] = { 1, 2 };
    func(&ar);

    return 0;
}
```

`template<typename T> bool func(T *var[])` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
template<typename T> bool func(T* var)
{
    return var == 0;
}
```

for `func(&ar);`, `T` will be `char[2]` and `T*` `char (*)[2]`.

or even:

```
template<typename T> bool func(T var)
{
    return var == 0;
}
```

for `func(&ar);`, `T` will be `char (*)[2]`.

If you want to restrict to C-style array, you may do:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N> bool func(T (*var)[N])
{
  return var == 0;
}
```

Comment: The last bit is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In

```
template<typename T> bool func(T** var)
```

when passing `&arr`, which is of type pointer to array `char(*)[2]`, `T` cannot be deduced. The compiler tries to match `T**` with `char(*)[2]`, and fails to find a match. Remember that `char[2]` is an array type, **not a pointer**, and **does not decay to a pointer** when matching a template. Help the compiler by using

```
template<typename T> bool func(T* var)
```

so now `T` can be deduced as `char[2]`, and `var` will be of type `char(*)[2]`. Or you can simply just use

```
template<typename T> bool func(T var)
```

in which case `T` is deduced as `char(*)[2]`, and `var` is of type `char(*)[2]` also.